# How to replace ZSH 4 with ZSH 5

Tags: zsh

I'd like to use zsh5 instead of the old 4. So I installed 5 with homebrew:
`brew install zsh`

and it did download the 5.0.2 tar and installed successfully, but after I restart iTerm2, type

`zsh --version`

it still shows me

`zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin12.0)`

I didn't remember how I installed 4, so not sure how to uninstall it? How could I remove 4 and use 5 as default?

when I looked /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/bin/, I see 2 files:
`zsh  zsh-5.0.2`

Should I link `zsh-5.0.2` to /bin/zsh ?

Comment: 4.3.11 comes with OS X; you almost certainly didn't install it. You can [set your login shell](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071025221744166) or use [`chsh`](http://superuser.com/questions/48226/how-do-i-set-my-shell-in-mac-os-x) to `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/bin/zsh`.

Comment: Before using `chsh` to change you login shell to `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/bin/zsh` you need to add the new shell to `/etc/shells`

Comment: @Francisco for my env, `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/bin/zsh` still shows 4.3.11, so change the login shell to `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/bin/zsh-5.0.2` may work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your older zsh version may be in a location in your path with higher priority than the homebrew installation.

```
$ which zsh # Check what path zsh refers to
/usr/local/bin/zsh
$ ls `which zsh` # It may be a link to homebrew's cellar
lrwxr-xr-x ... /usr/local/bin/zsh -> ../Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/bin/zsh
$ echo $PATH # Make sure /usr/local is before other places in you $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

You can also check which versions homebrew has installed and which is currently active using 
`brew info` like below. In this case there are two versions of `node` installed, and 0.10.13 is currently selected (see the `*`)

```
$ brew info node
node: stable 0.10.13, devel 0.11.4, HEAD
http://nodejs.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.12 (1104 files, 16M)
  Built from source
/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.13 (1085 files, 15M) *
  Built from source
```

If brew does have multiple versions listed you can switch between them using `brew switch node 0.10.12` for this example.

Comment: I do have `/usr/local/bin/` before `/bin` in the $PATH, so that's weird. As @simont said, zsh 4 may come from OSX by default. so `/bin/zsh` is not a link to anything. I finally make it work by a tricky way: rename `/bin/zsh` to something else, and `brew install zsh` again. This time ZSH settled in `/usr/local/bin/zsh` (not a link)

Comment: , but a terrible thing happened... when I tried to open a new tab in iTerm2, it just flash and disappeared very fast. I opened Terminal and saw the error message: /bin/zsh not found. Fortunately I find out that login shell can be modified in the Preference. The world is back alive now :) And glad to know the multiple versions usage on brew, Thank you very much!